# Play Framework Production Logging issue

Tags: playframework, java.util.logging

My current Loggers shows as below.

```
    10:31:11.015 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:11.901 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:12.115 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:13.001 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:13.215 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:14.101 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:14.315 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:15.201 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:15.415 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:15.702 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
10:31:16.301 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:16.515 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:17.401 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:17.614 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:18.501 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:18.715 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:19.600 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:19.815 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:20.701 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:20.915 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:21.801 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:22.015 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:22.901 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:23.115 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:24.001 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:24.215 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:25.101 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
10:31:25.315 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
```

It works perfectly during development and would like only to show info set up on Logger.info,

I'm using Play Framework Version 2.5.10

How do i solve this.

Logback XML is a below

```
<conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNCSTDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</appender>

<logger name="play" level="INFO" />
<logger name="application" level="INFO" />

<logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />

<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCSTDOUT" />
</root>
```

Comment: you'll need to post your logback.xml as well as the command line you're using to start the app

Comment: @LiorH my logback.xml is as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed Logback.xml from conf.